# Best practice for selecting "favourite" element from Set

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am facing the following problem: In my Spring Boot application there exists a person entity that can have multiple images. One of these images is marked as a default image - e.g. active profile picture. User can request person's general info (containing only default image) and person details (containing all of the images). As for now I have represented such scenario using the following:

Having person entity

```
class Person {

    var images: Set<Image> = mutableSetOf()

}
```

and Image entity

```
class Image {

    var isDefault: Boolean = false

}
```

I was wondering whether this is the best way to represent it. As an alternative this could be represented by `defaulImage` (representing the default one) and `images` (storing the rest) as two separate `Person` properites. This however will require more data manipulation on changing the default image (move previous default image to images, remove one object from images and set it as defaultImage). The application is running Neo4j database so instead of updating images properties it would require to modify the relations.

Which of the mentioned solutions is better? Is there any other, even better solution?

Answer (score 0):

It does depend highly on your use-case. Is the intention of your application to load all images nevertheless, go with the flag.

*OR* do you want only to load the `defaultImage` in 99% of the cases, create an additional relationship.
In this case you could avoid loading all the unrelated images when you load a `Person` by using a projection like:

```
class PersonProjection {

    Image getDefaultImage();
    //... other information
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#projections